# How to get my insert.php url in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to save my form data via jquery but i can't able to access it in my script.Can anyone help me.
URL access in script:  **url: 'admin.php?page=insert.php',**

My script

```
$(function () {
        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var schema_key = $("#schema_key").val(); 
          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'admin.php?page=insert.php',
            data: schema_key,
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });

        });

      });
```

Comment: do u want to use insert.php file only? As that is not the correct way to use AJAX in WP.

Comment: Then how can i insert form value without page refresh

Comment: Ok. I am adding an Answer for how to  use AJAX in WP. Please check

Comment: You should use the REST API for AJAX, don't make AJAX requests to specific files or pages

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add all the url , because if your script file is not located in the main page it will not access this  url: 'admin.php?page=insert.php',  tray to add the full url , url: 'domain.com.../admin.php?page=insert.php'

Comment: If i will add domain.com in that then how can i run it , Is it possible

Comment: emm you misunderstood  that , domain.com  was an example , you must add your domain , the full path to admin.php?page=insert.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    var site_url = window.location.hostname; // www.example.com
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var data = {
            action : 'insert',
            schema_key : $("#schema_key").val(),
      }; // adding action
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: site_url+'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: data,
        success: function () {
          alert('form was submitted');
        }
      }); // end of ajax

   }); // end of form submit

}); // end of $function
```

If you check the data that I am sending to ajax call there is one "action" parameter, and this action is responsible for defining a function for inserting the detail in the database.

Now you need to define a hook and callback function in your active theme's functions.php file  or your plugin file.

Syntax will be : `add_action( 'wp_ajax_$action', 'callback_function' )`;

So in your case it will be :

```
function wp_insert_schema_key() {
    $schema_key = $_POST["schema_key"];
    // Your code for inserting/updating in DB.
    echo "Success"; // response to be sent from AJAX call
    die;

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_insert', 'wp_insert_schema_key' );
```

For more information you can check  - https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins